# My sendmail isn't accepting connections

Tags: sendmail

I must be doing something wrong, but what?

I have a brand new VPS, and I'm using Webmin to get Sendmail running.

I'm just trying to accept mail for a certain domain and forward it to my other email address.

This is what I've done:

- I have Local Domains (Cw) configured to accept mail for my domain
- I have Address Mappings (virtuser) set to forward everything from my domain to my email address
- I stopped and started Sendmail
- I'm not using a firewall

But when I try to connect to my VPS on port 25, it says "connection refused".

When I try to connect from the VPS itself (using telnet localhost 25), it does connect.

So why can't I connect remotely?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check your firewall?

Comment: And this too: `netstat -npl | grep :25`

Comment: To get sendmail to listen to more than localhost: http://serverfault.com/a/673423/37681

Comment: Thanks HBruijn, that was it.  That worked.  If you answer this as an answer instead of a comment, I can mark it as the right answer.